# Get Immediate Child Property in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript

I am working with a minimally documented API. The response returns an object and, within that object, I have data I need...

i.e.

```
response: {
   locations: {
      location: {
         21421: { <-- this is random
           ...data needed in here
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The `21421` property appears to be a random number. I have no idea why, again, the documentation is very sparse. Is there any way to get the immediate child property of the `response.locations.location`? If so, that would greatly help me.

Thanks!

Comment: `for( var key in response.locations.location) ...`

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over it using [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

```
for(var prop in response.locations.location) {
    console.log(response.locations.location[prop])
}
```